# Numpy: replace each element in a row by the maximum of other elements in the same row

Tags: python, numpy

Let say we have a 2-D array like this:

```
>>> a
array([[1, 1, 2],
   [0, 2, 2],
   [2, 2, 0],
   [0, 2, 0]])
```

For each line I want to replace each element by the maximum of the 2 others in the same line.

I've found how to do it for each column separately, using numpy.amax and an identity array, like this:

```
>>> np.amax(a*(1-np.eye(3)[0]), axis=1)
array([ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.])
>>> np.amax(a*(1-np.eye(3)[1]), axis=1)
array([ 2.,  2.,  2.,  0.])
>>> np.amax(a*(1-np.eye(3)[2]), axis=1)
array([ 1.,  2.,  2.,  2.])
```

But I would like to know if there is a way to avoid a for loop and get directly the result which in this case should look like this:

```
>>> numpy_magic(a)
array([[2, 2, 1],
   [2, 2, 2],
   [2, 2, 2],
   [2, 0, 2]])
```

Edit: after a few hours playing in the console, I've finally come up with the solution I was looking for. Be ready for some mind blowing one line code:

```
np.amax(a[[range(a.shape[0])]*a.shape[1],:][(np.eye(a.shape[1]) == 0)[:,[range(a.shape[1])*a.shape[0]]].reshape(a.shape[1],a.shape[0],a.shape[1])].reshape((a.shape[1],a.shape[0],a.shape[1]-1)),axis=2).transpose()
array([[2, 2, 1],
   [2, 2, 2],
   [2, 2, 2],
   [2, 0, 2]])
```

Edit2: Paul has suggested a much more readable and faster alternative which is:

```
np.max(a[:, np.where(~np.identity(a.shape[1], dtype=bool))[1].reshape(a.shape[1], -1)], axis=-1)
```

After timing these 3 alternatives, both Paul's solutions are 4 times faster in every contexts (I've benchmarked for 2, 3 and 4 columns with 200 rows). Congratulations for these amazing pieces of code!

Last Edit (sorry): after replacing np.identity with np.eye which is faster, we now have the fastest and most concise solution:

```
np.max(a[:, np.where(~np.eye(a.shape[1], dtype=bool))[1].reshape(a.shape[1], -1)], axis=-1)
```

Comment: I hate to be critical, but _that_ is what you were looking for? Look, here is a readable version at less than half the length: `np.max(a[:, np.where(~np.identity(a.shape[1], dtype=bool))[1].reshape(a.shape[1], -1)], axis=-1)`

Comment: Well done @PaulPanzer! I've edited the question and starred your answer, even if I prefer this last one which is also faster if you replace np.identity with np.eye. Many thanks to you!

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit surprised this is fastest since in my experience advanced indexing is kind of slow. Maybe because it's just a handful of indices. Also, I used to think `eye` and `identity` are essentially the same. Lots of things to learn...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two solutions, one that is specifically designed for `max` and a more general one that works for other operations as well.

Using the fact that all except possibly one maximums in each row are the maximum of the entire row, we can use `argpartition` to cheaply find the indices of the largest two elements. Then in the position of the largest we put the value of the second largest and everywhere else the largest value. Works also for more than 3 columns.

```
>>> a
array([[6, 0, 8, 8, 0, 4, 4, 5],
       [3, 1, 5, 0, 9, 0, 3, 6],
       [1, 6, 8, 3, 4, 7, 3, 7],
       [2, 1, 6, 2, 9, 1, 8, 9],
       [7, 3, 9, 5, 3, 7, 4, 3],
       [3, 4, 3, 5, 8, 2, 2, 4],
       [4, 1, 7, 9, 2, 5, 9, 6],
       [5, 6, 8, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3]])
>>> 
>>> M, N = a.shape
>>> result = np.empty_like(a)
>>> largest_two = np.argpartition(a, N-2, axis=-1)
>>> rng = np.arange(M)
>>> result[...] = a[rng, largest_two[:, -1], None]
>>> result[rng, largest_two[:, -1]] = a[rng, largest_two[:, -2]]>>> 
>>> result
array([[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [9, 9, 9, 9, 6, 9, 9, 9],
       [8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9],
       [8, 8, 8, 8, 5, 8, 8, 8],
       [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9],
       [8, 8, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]])
```

This solution depends on specific properties of max.

A more general solution that for example also works for `sum` instead of `max` would be. Glue two copies of `a` together (side-by-side, not on top of each other). So the rows are something like `a0 a1 a2 a3 a0 a1 a2 a3`. For an  index `x` we can get all but `ax` by slicing `[x+1:x+4]`. To do this vectorized we use `stride_tricks`:

```
>>> a
array([[2, 6, 0],
       [5, 0, 0],
       [5, 0, 9],
       [6, 4, 4],
       [5, 0, 8],
       [1, 7, 5],
       [9, 7, 7],
       [4, 4, 3]])
>>> M, N = a.shape
>>> aa = np.c_[a, a]
>>> ast = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(aa, (M, N+1, N-1), aa.strides + aa.strides[1:])
>>> result = np.max(ast[:, 1:, :], axis=-1)
>>> result
array([[6, 2, 6],
       [0, 5, 5],
       [9, 9, 5],
       [4, 6, 6],
       [8, 8, 5],
       [7, 5, 7],
       [7, 9, 9],
       [4, 4, 4]])

# use sum instead of max
>>> result = np.sum(ast[:, 1:, :], axis=-1)
>>> result
array([[ 6,  2,  8],
       [ 0,  5,  5],
       [ 9, 14,  5],
       [ 8, 10, 10],
       [ 8, 13,  5],
       [12,  6,  8],
       [14, 16, 16],
       [ 7,  7,  8]])
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension solution.

```
np.array([np.amax(a * (1 - np.eye(3)[j]), axis=1) for j in range(a.shape[1])]).T
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Ethan's answer but with `np.delete()`, `np.max()`, and `np.dstack()`:

```
np.dstack([np.max(np.delete(a, i, 1), axis=1) for i in range(a.shape[1])])

array([[2, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 0, 2]])
```

- `delete()` "filters" out each column successively;
- `max()` finds the row-wise maximum of the remaining two columns
- `dstack()` stacks the resulting 1d arrays

If you have more than 3 columns, note that this will find the maximum of "all other" columns rather than the "2-greatest" columns per row.  For example:

```
a2 = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
np.dstack([np.max(np.delete(a2, i, 1), axis=1) for i in range(a2.shape[1])])

array([[[ 4,  4,  4,  4,  3],
        [ 9,  9,  9,  9,  8],
        [14, 14, 14, 14, 13],
        [19, 19, 19, 19, 18],
        [24, 24, 24, 24, 23]]])
```

Comment: Nice one, but I'm afraid it will be too slow with np.delete, and also any list comprehension is a kind of for loop...

Comment: Correct on both points @fbparis. Paul’s solution is pretty unbeatable here I believe